# Tkinter Canvas wont show image on c.create_image

Tags: image, numpy, tkinter, opencv, python

I have a canvas and I need to show an image that was taken with `cv2`’s VideoCapture, so I converted it with:

```py
img = Image.fromarray(img)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(master=window, image=img.resize((800, 600)))
```

but it just doesn’t show.

I’ve tried changing the photoImages master to the canvas which also didn’t work.

```py
def cv2tk(img, window):
    # fic the colors
    b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
    img = cv2.merge((r,g,b))

    # turn img into tkphoto
    img = Image.fromarray(img)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(master=window, image=img.resize((800, 600), Image.ANTIALIAS)) 
    
    # return img
    return imgtk

window = Tk()
window.geometry("800x600")

c = Canvas(window, width=800, height=600)
c.grid(row=0, column=0)

vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
val, frame = vc.read()
img = convert.cv2tk(frame, window)

c.create_image(0, 0, image=img)

while True:
    window.update()
```

I expect to get a window with a picture from the webcam in but in actual fact I get a blank window.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It maybe a bit late to answer. But here is a snippet which I was using.

As soon as you press <kbd>Space</kbd> an image will be captured and stored at the location where your script is present. And simultaneously, it will be read and displayed in `canvas` too.

```
import cv2
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cv2.namedWindow("Click Space or Escape")

canvas = Canvas(width=300, height=300, bg='black')
canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

img_counter = 0
while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    if not ret:
        print("failed to grab frame")
        break
    cv2.imshow("Click Space or Escape", frame)

    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k%256 == 27:
        # Press Escape to Close
        print("Escape Pressed .. Bye")
        break
    elif k%256 == 32:
        # Press Space for Image Capture
        img_name = "{}.png".format(img_counter)
        cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
        print("{} written!".format(img_name))
        img_counter += 1

        gif1 = PhotoImage(file=img_name)
        gif1 = gif1.zoom(17) 
        gif1 = gif1.subsample(28)
        canvas.create_image(10, 10, image=gif1, anchor=NW)
        mainloop()
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```